# How to find the count of TD that is null?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape a report that may have many rows.  I need to count two different aspects in the table.  First, the count where an href is present with a specific title.  Second, the number of occurrences where TD[9] is null.  I believe I have the first part figured out, but cannot seem to get the second count.

The specific table on this report has an ID of tbl1.  The table rows are roughly in the following format:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="URL1" title="Title1" ></a></td>
                <td><a href="URL2" title="Title2" ></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td><a href="URL3" title="Title3">text</a></td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
```

In C#, I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to pull the count of title Title3.  This appears to be working correctly.

```
foreach (HtmlNode results in htmlReport.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='tbl1']"))
{
    var countFirst = results.SelectNodes("//tr//td//a[not(@class) and @title='Title3']").Count;
}
```

In the same table, I want to count the number of occurrences where TD[9] in each row is null.  I've tried the following, but this results in an unhandled exception: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

```
   var countSecond = results.SelectNodes("//tr//td[9] == null").Count;
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.  Any clues?

Comment: `"//tr[.//td[9] == 'null']"`?

Comment: @RubensFarias Thanks for the suggestion.  This also results in expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Comment: `"//tr//td[position() = 9 and . = 'null']"`

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by null?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thank you! You made me realize it's not actually a null value in the TD, it's a nbsp.  `"//tr//td[position() = 9 and . = '&nbsp;']"` seems to work.